# SQL SELECT returns same item more than one time

Tags: sql, inner-join, distinct

I have the following SQL Command:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Notes 
INNER JOIN  AuthorizedPersons 
ON Notes.idPass = AuthorizedPersons.idPass 
AND AuthorizedPersons.Privileged = 0 
AND Notes.idUser =7
```

This returns the correct items! BUT returns the same item twice for each AuthorizedPerson that exists!

(Using DISTINCT does not solve the problem because items can have the same name.)

Query Results:
[image]

As you can see in the idPass 15 and 16 the description can be the same BUT idPass cannot since it's the primary key!

The query returns 3 times the idPass 30...

Comment: That would imply that you have two matching notes.  No mystery here.  If you want an answer, include sample data, desired results, and a proper database tag.

Comment: Of course a distinct ill not do the trick if you are listing different AuthorizedPerson. Try to list only notes and distinct ill work **"select distinct notes.*"**

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Where instead of the first AND.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Notes 
INNER JOIN  AuthorizedPersons 
ON Notes.idPass = AuthorizedPersons.idPass 
WHERE AuthorizedPersons.Privileged = 0 
AND Notes.idUser =7
```

Answer (score 0):

In the table `AuthorizedPersons` ,column starting with '`IdUs..`' repeating multiple times against the same `idPass`.That is why you are getting multiple rows against same value of `idpass`.For avoiding the duplicate records, you can either use a '`DISTINCT`' keyword after excluding that particular column or you can choose any one of the record from that duplicated record by eliminating the others.

[image]

Comment: Those `idUsers` repeating against the same `idPass` represent that those `idUser` have access to the `idPass` when this runs in the windows forms.

Comment: The problem is that this query will say those users that they can see 3 notes but those 3 notes are the same!

Comment: is it possible to avoid the column 'IDuser' or shall we make that column vaue as comma seperated (12,14,15)?

Comment: it's totally dispensable i just dont know how to